# Unable to copy from properties when Lookup included?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, html

In SharePoint Designer 2013 (for a SPO site) when working with Workflows, I would like to be able to copy the HTML from the Email Body field (see below). When I highlight the HTML and `Ctrl + C` I get a *ding* sound and the contents are not copied.

As a result, I've been extracting the HTML by copying the pieces between lookups. Is there a better/faster way to do this?

[image: example of HTML from Email Body Properties field]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the properties panel. Without opening the editor, click in the text field:
[image: properties panel]

Ctrl+C and you will copy the whole string. The lookups will be converted to plain text, once you edit it, you need to replace all of the lookups in the editor with the actual lookup...